# @JsonProperty seems to only work for non boolean members

Tags: java, json, serialization, fasterxml

I have an object I'm trying to map to JSON and everything seems to work marvelously, except for boolean members, as we can see below:

```
public class Foo implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty("this_does_not_work")
    private boolean isBar;

    @JsonProperty("this_works")
    private int bar;

    @JsonProperty("this_works_too")
    public boolean isBar() {
        return isBar;
    }

}
```

This would be serialized to this:

```
{
    this_works: ...,
    this_works_too: ...    
}
```

Why do boolean members can't have a `@JsonProperty` (but their getters do)?

Comment: How about if you change the method to `getBar()`, could there be a collision with name?

Comment: works for me, prints 3 fields in json. clean, recompile, retry

Comment: @AdamSkywalker It does print 3 fields, but that's just an example. Please remove the third `@JsonProperty` (from the getter) and tell me if it serializes to the `this_does_not_work` and `this_works` attributes :)

Comment: I reproduced some weird cases but it's for sure caused by variable naming. can you provide a real sample with problem? I have no desire to investigate why int and boolean vars with same names and random methods finally collided

Comment: @AdamSkywalker sure! Here it is: https://pastebin.com/EBd6KQ6t (this is the closest to something "real", but still I've hidden some properties for simplicity). Again, just so I'm clear, you can only rename a [BOOLEAN!] property by using a `@JsonProperty` on it's getter (unlikely for all other types). Thanks for the help!

Comment: your getter does not follow java naming conventions. if your boolean field has name enabled, getters name should be isEnabled or getEnabled. since your boolean field name is isEnabled, getters should be isIsEnabled or getIsEnabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summarising the statements from comments: if you change your boolean field name to `enabled`

```
@JsonProperty("custom_name")
private boolean enabled;

public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}

public void setEnabled(boolean isEnabled) {
    this.enabled = isEnabled;
}
```

it will give desired output `{ "custom_name" : true }`

The original problem is not following java field naming conventions:

```
@JsonProperty("custom_name")
@Column(name = "fl_enabled")
private boolean isEnabled;

public boolean isEnabled() {
    return isEnabled;
}

public void setEnabled(boolean isEnabled) {
    this.isEnabled = isEnabled;
}
```

When FasterXML serializes an object, it looks for fields and getters.

In your case, it found boolean field `isEnabled` and serialized it with `custom_name`.

Then it excluded getter of this boolean field from processing - possible getter names to exclude are `getIsEnabled` and 'isIsEnabled' - you don't have any.

Then it finds method `isEnabled` that looks like a getter for field `enabled`. So it takes its value and serializes it with key `enabled`.

So again, the problem is you should not name boolean fields with prefix `is`.

Comment: Somehow that does solve it and that's why I accepted it, however I dont quite get why the naming convention has to do with it (despite the fact it's wrongly named). Mind to explain in depth?

Comment: @YvesHenri added step by step explanation, thought it was clear

Comment: Got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who ends up here: this can also be caused by incorrect imports.

In my case, I should have used:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
```

But instead I incorrectly imported

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;
```