# Serialization problem with "is getter" to property name in jackson databind

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper, jackson-databind

I have a problem with serialization of "is getter" accessor to property name.
I have a class with boolean `isState()` accessor method and property with name `isState`.

[image]

During serialization I see that object mapper is convert `isState()` method as `state` property.

[image]

Of course I can use `@JsonProperty` annotation but I need to do it generically for all such cases.

Before `jackson-databind 2.12.0` it worked, unfortunately it stopped now because `AccessorNamingStrategy` has been added with a new way to find field names for getters. I can extend the `AccessorNamingStrategy` class and change the way to find field names, but it's too much code duplication to achieve such a minor goal. Issue: [Extract getter/setter/field name mangling from 'BeanUtil' into pluggable 'AccessorNamingStrategy'](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2800)

I tried to fight `setAccessorNaming` because it came out from version 2.12.0 and `setPropertyNamingStrategy` but unfortunately with poor results.

Edit:

I was able to fix the problem like this (image), if anyone has something better please let me know.

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't name boolean properties with `is` as per (Java Bean spec)[https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/] 8.3.2 - which is assumed by Jackson. See also - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47293589/jsonproperty-seems-to-only-work-for-non-boolean-members.

Comment: If we are talking about Java handling (and not Kotlin), I don't think behavior before 2.12 would have been different: `isState()` does indeed infer property with name `state`, and would not have become "isState" JSON property. So that particular change should not be relevant...